# React-testing-library: Could not find "store" in the context of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I'm quite new to testing so try to be gentle! I am trying to set up react-testing-library and I'm stuck with a confusing error message:

I defined a custom renderer that contains all my providers incl. redux `Provider`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { defaultTheme } from 'shared/theme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from 'reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const AllTheProviders = ({ children }) => {
  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
            {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
  )
}

const customRender = (ui, options?) =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options })

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'

// override render method
export { customRender as render }
```

But when trying to execute the test I am receiving the error Message:

> Error: Uncaught [Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the
>   context of "Connect(withRouter(Header))". Either wrap the root
>   component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to
>    and the corresponding React context consumer to
>   Connect(withRouter(Header)) in connect options.]

As far as I can see, I included the store. Is there a way around this?

*This question is not a duplicate of: [Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(SportsDatabase)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211739/invariant-violation-could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props-of-c)
Since it involves a global renderer.*

Comment: how did you end up fixing this?

Comment: I haven't really ... I think the best solution is to design the app with testability in mind and a strong container-view scheme so that you don't have to mock the entire story.

Comment: i had the same problem and i figured it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765183/react-testing-library-redux-could-not-find-store-in-the-context-of-connect . i figured it out by looking at this repo and backtracing what he was doing that i wasn't https://github.com/Lemoncode/react-testing-by-example.git

yeh for sure container view is the way to go. don't connect() unless it's the page root

Comment: thanks for the resources!

Answer (score 1):

The `store` needs to be mocked in order to test properly. I suggest to use [`redux-mock-store`](https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store) library to achieve that but it's up to your preference.

What I would try in your case is the following in the test file:

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const mockStore = configureMockStore();
const store = mockStore({ /* here you can create a mock object for the reducer */ });

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
                     { /* your components */ }
                  </Provider>, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

I hope this gives you the idea and helps!